Minimum edges (queries) required to distinguish hidden colors on graph nodes?
Suppose we have an $n$-vertex graph, and each of the $n$ vertices are colored one of $k$ colors. However, we do not know what their colors are. We are only allowed to query as follows: if there is an edge between two nodes, it will tell us whether the two nodes have 1) the same color or 2) different colors. So for example, if $n=3$ and $k =2$, then we only need two edges to determine which edges have the same or different colors. But if $n=4$ and $k=3$, and if we only have $v_1 - v_2 - v_3 - v_4$, then we can't tell if $v_1$ and $v_3$ have the same color. How many edges do we need to fully distinguish colors between all nodes?

Another example is that if we generate all ${n\choose 2} = O(n^2)$ edges (ie $p=1$), then of course we are able to distinguish everyone. But in particular I'm wondering if we can do strictly better, ie $o(n^2) edges$? Like even $O(n^{1.999})$ would be nice.
In particular, if we take an $n$-vertex random graph with fixed $k$ and generate edges with probability $p$, what threshold results are there on $p$ to fully distinguish nodes whp?
In general, what results/references are there on such problems?

Thanks in advance!

An interesting probabilistic problem might be: if we choose both the graph at random (generating edges with probability $p$) and color the vertices uniformly at random, at which point can we distinguish all the colors with high probability? (I suspect that for $k\ge 3$, the threshold is the point where, with high probability, each vertex has a neighbor of the same color - which should happen once $p \ge (k + \epsilon) \frac{\log n}{n}$. But that might take some work to prove.)

@MishaLavrov That's an interesting question! I believe a sufficient condition would be for every subgraph with same-color vertices to be connected. Moreover, it might necessary condition too - for otherwise we can apply a similar argument to your counterexample in the main answer - though I'm not sure if the colors being uniformly picked gives us more info. But I don't know enough about graphs to see whether it is easy to prove this with standard results haha

It's not a necessary condition: you can also uniquely identify the color of a vertex if it has neighbors of every other color, and you've identified their colors. But this should be much less likely at the threshold value. My suggested value for $p$ is my guess for when each color becomes connected. Actually, this might be something we can just deduce from the connectivity threshold of $G_{n,p}$.

If $k=2$, then any connected graph will do, so it's enough to have $n-1$ edges. (The threshold for connectivity in random graphs is well-known.)
However, if $k\ge 3$, then all $\binom n2$ edges are necessary. Suppose vertices $x$ and $y$ are not adjacent, and all our queries tell us that $x$ has a different color from all its neighbors, $y$ has a different color from all its neighbors, and all other adjacent vertices have the same color. Then we cannot determine if $x$ and $y$ have the same color as each other.

This is lovely, thank you! Btw are there any references/keywords you'd suggest to read up on results/techniques for these random graph threshold property thingies?

Generally speaking, Frieze and Karonski's textbook Introduction to Random Graphs is a good introduction.

(I might have the wrong interpretation of this question, like whether it's for a specific setup, or for an all-possible answers to the question setup.) This is not true. Look up uniquely 4-colorable planar graphs also known as Apollonian networks. For $k = 4$, if we know that vertices 1, 2, 3 are all differently colored, then any vertex connected to all of them and is also differently colored, must then be of the same color as each other. So even though they may not be adjacent, we can determine if they have the same color.

@CalvinLin As I understood the question, we're not assuming a proper coloring. Rather, the queries tell us, for each of the edges of the graph, whether the coloring is proper at that edge.
